# Running command from Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, sed, terminal

I see unusual behaviour when executing a command from Ruby.  When I run

```
`find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e  's/\/\/static.squarespace.com/http:\/\/static.squarespace.com/g' {} \;`
```

from a terminal, it works, but when I try to do same in Ruby with

```
`system(find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/\/\/static.squarespace.com/http:\/\/static.squarespace.com/g' {} \;)`
```

I get

> `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

How may I do that within Ruby succesfully?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to put some `"`s into your question; so given that the code you have is not executable, we can't find the problem with 100% certainty. Always copy-paste your problem as exactly as possible. But it is probable that you need to double up on your backslashies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you double escape the backslash - otherwise `\;` becomes just `;`. This works:

```
cmd = "find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's#\/\/static.squarespace.com#http:\/\/static.squarespace.com#g' {} \\;"
system(cmd)
```

Comment: Now m getting `sed: 1: "s///static.squarespace. ...": bad flag in substitute command: 's'`

Comment: I see - updated answer. Using a `#` as a delimiter instead of `/`